# Add to JSON array

Tags: couchbase, sql++

How can I append a new element to the existing array using N1QL?

```
[
{
  "address": "127.0.0.1",
  "time": 0
},
{
  "address": "127.0.0.1",
  "time": 0
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set to update the data

```
 ARRAY_APPEND(field, { "adress":"127.0.0.1", "time":null }) 

 where "key you need to use as reference' = "referemce data"
```

Comment: this will update the JSON and append the new value to the array

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit and write a full statement example? What type of statement should I use? Update? And how do I format the WHERE condition

Comment: for that you need to elaborate your question, which fields you want to Update? is it adress? time? if you just want to Append, the ARRAY_APPEND() will do that as I said before

Comment: I just want to append yes, so the whole JSON document contains an array with elements consisting of these fields: address & time, but now what's the key I need to use as reference?

Comment: well you are to say which keys you want. if those datas are important you need to have a key to reference them: For example, what is the name of this object? if it has, you can use the name as a key to find it. example: "title": "adventure",
    "custom": [
     {"modified": "a01","time": 200},
     {"modified": "a02","time": 201},
     {"modified": "a03","time": 202},
     ]
    }

Comment: The document id is 'login_history:username' and each element represents a single login. Each time a different login is detected, I'm going to want to append to that array.

Comment: So then: UPDATE `login_history` USE KEYS "username" 

ARRAY_APPEND("username",{ "adress":"127.0.0.1", "time":0}) 



 where "username" = "name of the user you're updating"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200187/discussion-between-indrz-and-lucas-soares).